# Haskellにてparse error on input |の原因がわかりません

Tags: haskell

コード6行目に表題のエラーが出て原因がわかりません。
インデントもしてるし余分な=も入ってないのにエラーになる原因が見つけられません。
ご指導のほどよろしくお願いします。

```
data T = T {x::Either _ Int, y::Maybe Int}
f = \t -> case t of
  T x y
    Just y
      | x :: Right Int -> x+y
      | x :: Left _ -> x
    Nothing -> 0
    _ -> undefined
```

Comment: これはどういうことをしたいプログラムなのでしょうか……？　もしかして、パターンマッチをネストさせようとしているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

やりたいのは、`T`型の値`y`が`Just`の場合と`Nothing`の場合とで処理を分けたい、ということでしょうか？
その場合、下記のように、もう一つ`case`式を書かないといけません。

```hs
data T = T {x::Either _ Int, y::Maybe Int}
f = \t -> case t of
  T ex my ->
      case my of
        Just y ->
          case ex of
              Right x -> x + y
              Left e -> e
        Nothing -> 0
  _ -> undefined
```

上記の書き換え方の例の通り、残念ながら、`x`が`Right`の場合と`Left`の場合とでのかき分け方も正しくありません（ガード構文と間違えている？）。

`case`式の使い方についてさらに指摘しますと、`T`型のように値コンストラクターが一つだけの型の値については、`case`式で場合分けする必要はありません。
以下のように、関数の引数でパターンマッチすれば十分でしょう。

```hs
data T = T {x::Either _ Int, y::Maybe Int}
f (T ex my) =
    case my of
      Just y ->
        case ex of
            Right x -> x + y
            Left e -> e
      Nothing -> 0
```

`case`式の場合と異なり、関数の引数で直接パターンマッチする場合、`(T ex my)`のように、カッコで囲うのを忘れないでください。

入れ子のパターンマッチと関数の引数でのパターンマッチ両方を活用すると、下記のようにも書けます。

```
data T = T {x::Either _ Int, y::Maybe Int}
f (T (Right x) (Just y)) = x + y
f (T _         Nothing)  = 0
f (T (Left e)  _)        = e
```

※一度のパターンマッチですべての引数をパターンマッチさせてる関係上、マッチさせる順番を少し入れ替えている点にご注意ください。

また、このコードのコンパイルエラーをなくすには、さらに`T`型の定義を変え必要があります。

```hs
data T = T {x::Either _ Int, y::Maybe Int}
```

の、`Either _ Int`の箇所ですが、型定義における型注釈で`_`という構文を使用することはできません。
`case`式を直しても、下記のようなエラーが出るでしょう。

```
    Wildcard ‘_’ not allowed
      in the definition of data constructor ‘T’
  |
1 | data T = T {x::Either _ Int, y::Maybe Int}
  |
```

なので、適当な型を指定する必要があります。
どの型にするべきか、についてはこの回答では割愛します。質問者がそもそもやりたいことがなんなのかがわからないので。